# $scope переменная не обновляется в html при её изменении в контроллере в фукнции

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой изменения значения $scope.lastName. Дело в том, что при клике на блок оттуда считывается информация в функцию и в переменную $scope.lastName должно передаваться имя, которое потом показывается в html в блоке подстверждения. 
Я поделал тесты, переменную видно только если я явно укажу её значение в начале контроллера (вне функции которая запускается при клике), в функции вывожу аллерт и он показывает новоё значение, но в html в блоке ничего не меняется, не могу понять почему?

Блок, в котором записываются пользователи:

```
<div id="wrapperForUsers" class="divsStyles" ng-
controller="ActiveUsersCtrl">
<div class="divsStyles, userDiv" ng-repeat="user in usersData | 
filter:filterID" ng-click="confirmationToRequestToTolkFunction(user)"> //Запуск функции тут
    <div class="userPhoto"></div>
    <div class="userDivsInformation" data-name="{{user.name}}" data-
id="{{user.ID}}"><p>{{user.name+', '+user.age}}<div>Сейчас <span 
style="color: green">{{user.where}}</span></div></p></div>
    <div class="userDivsInformation"><p>{{user.country+', 
'+user.city}}</p><p>{{user.information}}</p></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Блок, который появляется при клике:

```
<div id="confirmation" class="divsStyles">
<p>Вы действительно хотите отправить заявку {{lastName}} ?</p>//Тут проблема (если новый вариант переменной всеравно старый вариант
<button type="button" value="send" style="float:left">Да</button>
<button type="button" value="remove" style="float:right;">Нет</button>
</div>
```

Функция при клике:

```
$scope.confirmationToRequestToTolkFunction = function(user){
    $scope.lastChosenID = user.ID;
    $scope.lastName = user.name;
    holder.style.display = 'block';
    confirmation.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Вся проблема в том, что не отобажается новый обновленный вариант $scope.lastName

Comment: ну это ж ангуляр, какие `.style.display = 'block';`???

Comment: я понемногу переделываю с обычного js) но разве это может помешать перезаписи переменной?

Comment: сделай пример, который можно запустить, например на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) или тут в сниппете. Судя по предоставленному коду - все должно отлично работать

Comment: не могу понять как в plunker заставить работать angular

Comment: [Например так](http://plnkr.co/edit/N5lLFN5tPfMVyKiChVJh?p=preview) измени шаблон так, чтобы воспроизводилась твоя проблема

Comment: нууу ) в plunkere работает, но там сильно упрощенная версия. Может я где-то туплю я не понимаю. У меня переходит по ссылке active-users, подключается к ней соответствующий контроллер, но все что связанно с динамическим изменением начинает тупить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62522/discussion-between-grundy-and-horchynskyi).